# Conjecture About Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

I have recently started to learn a bit of number theory, and I just wanted to pose the following problem out of curiosity. I don't know what the answer is myself. Here is the problem.

Prove or disprove: there exists a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$, $f(n)= 
   |\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_in^i |$, where each $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, such that $f(n)$ is prime for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

That is false, take $n=k\times a_0, k\in\mathbb Z$, then $a_0|f(n)$.

Comment: Which would be fine if $a_0 = \pm 1$ (which cannot be because $|a_0|=f(0)$ is supposed to be a prime).

Comment: But then even $f(0)$ would not be prime !

Comment: Exactly, that's my point.